# Algebra 2 probability problem

Tags: probability

It is known that 30% of all people own dogs and, independently, 40% of all people own cats. In a survey, 60% of people who only own dogs say they need a pet hair vacuum cleaner, 75% who own only cats say they need a vacuum cleaner, and 90% of people who own both pets say they need a vacuum cleaner. Pete buys a vacuum cleaner. What is the probability that he has cats (with or without dogs)?

The answer is .746. I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: the first thing I would do is draw a [Venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram), that always helps with problems like these

Comment: Perhaps you are supposed to assume that people who own neither cats nor dogs never need a vacuum cleaner.  I know this might not make much sense to a llama owner like me, but it does give you the suggested answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $P(\text{dog})=.3$ and $P(\text{cat})=.4$, so it follows that $P(\text{dog and cat})=.3\times.4=.12$.

But then $P(\text{only dog})$ becomes $.3-.12=.18$ and similarly, $P(\text{only cat})$ becomes $.4-.12=.28$.

Finally, $$P(\text{cat|vacuum})=\frac{(.12\times.9)+(.28\times.75)}{(.18\times.6)+(.12\times.9)+(.28\times.75)}\approx .746$$

The numerator is the probability that one owns a cat, dog, and owns a vacuum cleaner, plus the probability that one owns just a cat and a vacuum cleaner. The denominator is all that plus the probability that someone owns just a dog and a vacuum cleaner.

I should note that you cannot deduce from the information provided that $P(\text{only dog}) = .18$, and similarly for $P(\text{only cat})$ but you cannot go about solving this without that assumption.